# Pl/SQL code correction

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a code that will compute the number of days in year 2020 for each month. My original code has three columns but my assignment requires creating only two column. I am having trouble computing my code to work only using two columns. I was wondering if someone can help me solve this problem by removing the count column and making sure my code still produce the correct output.

```
set serveroutput on

--- Drop Table
DROP TABLE MONTH_DAYS;
--- Create Table 
CREATE TABLE MONTH_DAYS(cnt number(2), Month_ Varchar(9),Days_ Number(2));

Declare
months varchar2(10);
days varchar2(10);
i Binary_integer := 0;

Begin
loop
i:= i+1;
if i = 13 then
exit;
end if;
insert into month_days(cnt, month_, days_)
values
(i, to_char(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i), 'Month'),
to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i)), 'DD'));

select month_ , days_ 
into months, days 
from month_days 
where cnt = i;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Month: '||Months||'Days: '|| Days);
end loop;
end; 
/
```

Comment: Please pick an answer as 2 of us have spent valuable time helping you solve your homework problem. Please return the favor by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lot of code, for something that can be done in one line:

```
create table month_days as
select to_char(to_date('01-'||rownum||'-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'MON') month,
       to_char(last_Day(to_date('01-'||rownum||'-2020','dd-mm-yyyy')),'dd') days
  from dual connect by level <=12
/
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: the assignment requires me to write a loop in order to compute the number of days in each month for year 2020

Comment: Ok, well, I'm not going to do your assignment for you.  You should be able to adapt my SQL back into your PL/SQL block.  Give it a try.  If you still have problems, post specific details of what you did and why it didn't work, and I'm sure we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak I disagree-- the solution you gave was concise, but a "connect by" is hardly something a novice will be able to unravel with ease unless they're very far along, and I dont think they are. I do not think we should be doing assignments for people-- but if we're answering a question that mentions an assignment, we have to take the requirements into account.

Comment: Joe, I agree, that the connect by is likely something that a novice would not be familiar with, but, I was thinking, if he's writing a PL/SQL loop, he doesn't need the connect by, as the rows would be driven by a PL/SQL loop.  Specifically, I was thinking he could adapt the text between the 'select' and the 'from', into his code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you're asking.
The first appears to be using the returning into clause of the insert statement

```
insert into month_days(month_, days_)
values
(to_char(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i), 'Month'),
to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i)), 'DD'))
returning month_,days_ into months,days;
```

The returning clause can return any of the data used in an insert statement back to pl/sql as variables (very similar to your select into statement you used later in your code).
With this code, you no longer need the select into, and the cnt column.

I also don't know if you've learned "for" statements or not in your class, but I'd recommend that over the way you're using a loop, incrementing I and and IF statement-- the for statement is shorter and easier to read. You can read the docs about the "for loop" [here](http://psoug.org/definition/LOOP.htm)

Hope this has been some help, and feel free to follow up with further questions, I'd like to help you do this in a way that promotes good habits in the future. I don't really like answering assignment type questions, but I will if I can help you understand what's going on.

Comment: I have tried adding the 'returning' into my code and removing the cnt column and select into but I receive an error saying  'too many values'.

Comment: I thought about using for statement but was having trouble so I use the if statement example I learn in class. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: the assignment requires calling the column 'month_' and 'days_'

Comment: Oh I see the problem. I left "I" in the insert. I'll update it to remove that
Edit: Try now.

Comment: yes, thank you I was able to solve the issue I appreciate the help

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please don't forget to mark the problem as answered.